# Comprobación de exenciones diferentes con el mismo nombre de archivo en java

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

**Mi pregunta es como puedo evaluar distintas extensiones de un archivo con el mismo nombre contenido dentro de un arreglo de String?** Por ej: Dentro del arreglo tengo:

**A22_ALGO.txt**

**A22_ALGO.exe**

El método que e logrado hacer me evalúa correctamente si un archivo contenido en el arreglo es del mismo nombre pero distinta extensión, en ese caso que no haga nada con ese archivo. Pero si tengo:

**A22_ALGO.txt**

**A22_ALGO.exe**

**B20_ALGO.txt**

El archivo con el nombre **B20_ALGO.txt** si solo existe con esa extensión, sin la existencia de alguna otra debería de mostrarme en pantalla que ese archivo existe, sin embargo, no lo hace.

El método que tengo es:

```
private void evaluarNombre() {
        String[] array = arrayArchivos.toArray(new String[arrayArchivos.size()]);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
                //Comprobamos que los nombres sean los mismos
                if (array[i].substring(0, array[i].lastIndexOf(".")).equals(array[j].substring(0, array[j].lastIndexOf(".")))) {
                    //Si tienen el mismo nombre, comprobamos que la extension sea diferente
                    if (!array[i].substring(array[i].lastIndexOf("."), array[i].length()).equals(array[j].substring(array[j].lastIndexOf("."), array[j].length()))) //Si tiene el mismo nombre y diferente extensión pintamos en pantalla
                    {
                        System.out.println("Son iguales con diferente extensión: ");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Necesito realizar esta comprobación ya que la carpeta donde levanto los archivos se agregan e eliminan constantemente. Desde ya gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tienes ningun `system.out` para cuando no coincide los nombres, agrega caso else:

```
private void evaluarNombre() {
    String[] array = arrayArchivos.toArray(new String[arrayArchivos.size()]);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            //Comprobamos que los nombres sean los mismos
            if (array[i].substring(0, array[i].lastIndexOf(".")).equals(array[j].substring(0, array[j].lastIndexOf(".")))) {
                //Si tienen el mismo nombre, comprobamos que la extension sea diferente
                if (!array[i].substring(array[i].lastIndexOf("."), array[i].length()).equals(array[j].substring(array[j].lastIndexOf("."), array[j].length()))) //Si tiene el mismo nombre y diferente extensión pintamos en pantalla
                {
                    System.out.println("Son iguales con diferente extensión: ");
                }
            }else{
                System.out.println("Nombres no coinciden. "+array[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Espero sea esa tu duda.